# Using PDO with SELECT Options

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to use `PDO` for a `SELECT` Option, this is my `functions.php` code:

```
<?php
    class Benefits
    {
        public function fetch_all()
        {
            global $pdo;

            $benfitssql = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM lkup_benefits');
            //$benfitssql->execute();

            while ($row = $benfitssql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $ops.= "<option value='" . $row['BenefitOption'] . "'>"
                    . $row['Benfits'] . "</option>";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

This is my main page:

```
<label>Benefit Type</label>

<select class="select2_category form-control" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1" id="benefittype" name="benefittype">
    <?php echo $ops; ?>
</select>
```

When I select the `SELECT` Option, it opens with no records, why would this be, what have I missed?

Comment: Perhaps your function `fetch_all()` doesn't `return $ops;` ?

Comment: `global $pdo` in a `class`? Are you kidding me? The whole point of a class is you can re-use that code, regardless of the rest of the project. Your class can _only_ be used if there is a global `$pdo` variable that happens to be an instance of `PDO`. Kill this code before it hatches. Also: `PDO` offers a pretty consistent and clear-cut API as it is, no point in wrapping it in another class, you're just adding dead weight

Answer (score 2):

There are two essential flaws with your code

first, you should never format HTML inside of a function,
second, you should **return** something from the function

```
class Benefits {
    public function fetch_all() {
        global $pdo;
        return $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM lkup_benefits') ->fetchAll();
    }
}
?>
<label>Benefit Type</label>
<select class="select2_category form-control" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1" id="benefittype" name="benefittype">
<?php foreach ($benefits->fetch_all() as $row): ?>
    <option value="<?=$row['BenefitOption']?>"><?=$row['Benfits']?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Third. You should initialise $ops before you .= it.

Comment: Third you should not rely, or think of using a `global` variable _inside a method!_

Comment: Thanks for the replies, why should I never use a function to return something? I ask this as it's what I've seen through a tutorial, on this they used the function to return a list on to a page

Comment: '@EliasVanOotegem how do you mean use a global variable inside a method?

Comment: @Jez: Say I want to use your class: `<?php $b = new Benefits();`, but I don't have a global `$pdo` variable lying around... I can't use your code. Say I did have a global `$pdo`, but it was not assigned (yet), or I changed it from `PDO` instance to `null`: your code fails. What if I need more than 1 connection (several db's etc...)? If I use a _global_ connection var, then your class is as pointless as a broken pencil. Oh, and you **should return**, not _"not"_ return, your posted code doesn't have a `return` statement

Comment: A class should be a self-contained entity: all it needs has to be provided through methods (constructor, setters and getters), at no point should it resort to using variables outside its own scope (ie: vars that are neither arguments nor properties). just add `public function __construct(PDO $connection) { $this->pdo = $connection;}`, and create the instance like so: `new Benefits($pdo);` make sure to add `protected $pdo = null;` to your class definition, too

Comment: Yes sorry that was my mistake in reading the "not". I'll look into the global methods, PDO is new to me. Once posting the code above into my code it still doesnt return any values in the list

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49953/discussion-between-jez-and-elias-van-ootegem)

Comment: "you should never format HTML inside of a function" -- that needs to be given context; *you should never format HTML inside a function, unless the responsibility of that function is to format HTML*; for example, rendering HTML.

Comment: You are welcome to add it to my answer. unlike previous edit, this is a sensible one. However, quite a nitpicking though

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to Your Common Sense's answer, everything he said is correct, but he forgot (You *forgot* right?) one important detail: **[Globals are evil!](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)**

If your function requires a PDO object in order to work, just ask for it!

```
class Benefits {
    public function fetch_all(PDO $pdo) { //Ask for what you need in the constructor!
        return $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM lkup_benefits') ->fetchAll();
    }
}
?>
<label>Benefit Type</label>
<select class="select2_category form-control" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1" id="benefittype" name="benefittype">
<?php foreach ($benefits->fetch_all($pdo) as $row): //Pass it in when you need it! ?>
    <option value="<?=$row['BenefitOption']?>"><?=$row['Benfits']?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

That makes your class a whole lot more flexible, you now don't silently rely on the fact that there's a global object called $pdo and is of PDO type, **the code won't work otherwise, and it's very clear now!**.

There are other issues, like mixing your data fetching logic with your presentation logic, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks, I've now changed the function to show above and changed the SELECT Option to the above also. I call the page with the function in it at the top of my main page. The SELECT doesn't show any data though